# Why does this equation return this value? JAVA

Tags: java

It should be returning the value of 70.28, but it returns 0.0. I don't understand why it does this. The equation is set up. I had it set in a method, but I took it out so I can keep those values and use them later on. It worked inside the method, but now that it's out of the method it doesn't work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Assignment51
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      /*
      Four Categories are used as a basis for compiling a rating:
      1. Percentage of completions
      2. Average yards gained
      3. Percentage of touchdown passes per attempt
      4. Percentage of interceptions per attempt
      */

      // DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.000");

      String input;        //get user input
      String name;         //player name
      int completion;      //number of completions in percentages
      int yardsGained;     //number of yards gained
      int tdpasses;        //number of touchdown passes
      int interceptions;   //number of interceptions
      int attempts;        //number of attempts
      int yards;           //number of yards
      double score;        //passer score
      double totalScore;   //total score
      double totalPoints;  //total award points
      double total;        //total sum
      double awardPoints1 = 0.0;         //awarded points +/- 2.375
      double awardPoints2 = 0.0;
      double awardPoints3 = 0.0;
      double awardPoints4 = 0.0;
      double percentComp;
      double pointRatingComp;
      int num1;


      //get player name
      name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type in the player name");

      //get number of attemps/passes
      input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type in the TOTAL number of passes");
      attempts  = Integer.parseInt(input);


      //get number of completed passes
      input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type in the number of COMPLETED passes");
      num1 = Integer.parseInt(input); 
      percentComp = ((num1 / attempts) * 100); 
      //DEBUG
      System.out.println(percentComp);
       //point rating
      pointRatingComp = ((percentComp - 30) * .05);






      //Creating Methods

      double PctCompletion = PctCompletion(attempts, percentComp);
      double AvgYardsGain = AvgYardsGain(attempts);
      double PctTouchdown = PctTouchdown(attempts);
      double PctInterceptions = PctInterceptions(attempts);
```

Comment: Java integer division. Use `float` or `double`

Comment: Yes, changing `int num1` to `double num1` fixed it. Thank you :)